# localStorage replacement?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I needed a simple calendar where users event can be displayed and set by user, found this https://codepen.io/code-boxx/pen/NWzqazY by code-boxx but its using localStorage.

```
// (C2) LOAD DATA FROM LOCALSTORAGE
cal.data = localStorage.getItem("cal-" + cal.sMth + "-" + cal.sYear);
if (cal.data==null) {
  localStorage.setItem("cal-" + cal.sMth + "-" + cal.sYear, "{}");
  cal.data = {};
} else { cal.data = JSON.parse(cal.data); }
```

```html
async function getEvents() {
  fetch(data_url, {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
    }})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      data.events.forEach((element) => {
        eDate = new Date(element.event_date);
        events.push({
          date: `${eDate.getMonth() + 1}/${eDate.getDate()}/${eDate.getFullYear()}`,
          type: element.event_type,
          note: element.event_note,
          status: element.event_status,
          id:element.event_id,
        });
        cal.draw();
      });
    });
}
```

Im loading event from the server with fetch and need to replace the current localStorage methotd with something else so it can be displayed.
Im novice with JS, any help, suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: If you want many people to store data than you would need a back end language and database.

Comment: If the events are stored on the server, you need another controller function to save the event, and you use `fetch()` to send the event there.

Comment: Yes there is a update event and delete event fetch in the old project what Ill move over once I figure out how to display the events.

Comment: Basically I need to modify the above code to store and load from the event array instead from localStorage.